# Can Kubuntu simulate the Aero Desktop Peek functionality from Windows 7

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Windows 7 has an Aero feature that allows you to make all windows on a workspace transparent to let you look at desktop.

[image]

I already have a shortcut setup for "show desktop" but that doesn't do so without minimizing all of the windows running on a given workspace.

Is there any way to make all windows completely transparent by moving the mouse to one corner of the screen?

The reason why I don't want to minimize any windows because WINE has a slight glitch when running PokerStars - WINE will completely freeze if you minimize a running table window w/ PokerStars.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the closest for this case it would be the "Opacify" function inside of the CompizConfig Settings Manager, which will allow you to define which key binding you wish to activate it. When in use, the "opacify" function will decrease the opacity level of the active window in order to allow you to "see" the items below it. This behavior is also observed in the windows placed in lower places.

The next screenshot illustrates the options that can be configured via CompizConfig Settings Manager Opacify function:

[image]

The next screenshot shows the "opacify" function in action.

[image]

When the mouse arrow goes far from the window size, the "opacify" function starts to work.

However, the behavior of the transparent windows can be handled via de Commands section and its respective bindings, as shown for the Aero Snap function shown in this answer: [Is there any Window Manager like the Windows 7's for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54881/is-there-any-window-manager-like-the-windows-7s-for-ubuntu/54917#54917) but I haven't tried that yet. I hope you find a better solution because of the commands/bindings may become a hard work.

Good luck!

Comment: Is there anything similar to this function in KWin?  I'm not really fond of ComizConfig on Kubuntu, and KWin has a lot of features that I want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You could run "PokerStars" on a different workspace. Then when you need to access your desktop you could always switch to a different workspace where the desktop is accessible.

It's not an answer to your question, but maybe a solution.

Comment: That doesn't work either... switching workspace will freeze WINE as well when running PokerStars... tried this as a way to find a way around this issue but as far I know there isn't any way to fix this as of yet.