# Is there any Window Manager like the Windows 7's for Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.10, window-manager

In Windows 7, if you drag a window to the top of the screen, it will maximize, and if you drag to the side, it will restore to half size of the screen on that side.

Is there any window manager or plugin for Nautilus with this features?

Comment: Yes. This feature is available with Ubuntu 11.04. Which ubuntu version are you using?
For more information, please read and view the video on this page. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/aero-snap-in-ubuntu-unity-video/

Comment: @Amey Jah Can I install it to Ubuntu 10.10?

Comment: I am not sure. But give it a try. Ubuntu 11.04 uses modified/pre configured a compiz plugin called "Compiz Grid Plugin". This plugin is available in compiz-fusion-plugins-extra package. 

Additionally, take a look at following link on how to set aero snap for 10.10
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1626255

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unity, the default desktop for 11.04, does the top-screen maximize and the left/right screen thing by default, however it is not available for 10.10.

Answer (score 4):

Kwin, the window manager that comes with KDE behaves almost exactly like Windows 7 in its newer versions.

Comment: Well, in the manner in question, anyway. There's also a tiled window mode where windows are automatically sized and positioned...

Comment: It can also snap windows to a quarter of the screen by dragging to the corners..

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in the past, give this a try and let's see if is yet working.

In CompizConfig Settings Manager, let's choose the option "Commands" and let's find the list of available commands. Then:

[image]

In Command 0

```
WIDTH=`xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:' | cut -f 2 -d ':' | cut -f 1 -d 'x'` && HALF=$(($WIDTH/2)) && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,$HALF,-1
```

In Command 1

```
WIDTH=`xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:' | cut -f 2 -d ':' | cut -f 1 -d 'x'` && HALF=$(($WIDTH/2)) && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,$HALF,0,$HALF,-1
```

In Command 2

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Now, clic on the "Edge Bindings" and set the next options:

```
Run Command 0 - Left 
Run Command 1 - Right
Run Command 2 - Top
```

And it will look like this:

[image]

If you wish you can add a small delay in the "Edge Trigger delay" option in the "General Options" of the CompizConfig Settings Manager main screen. 400 miliseconds will do the trick.

Comment: my compiz config have a different interface, I found how to config the edges, but I cant find where to config the commands.. please, see my update with a screenshot

Comment: ops, I was using Simple CompizConfig..

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't worked. But it was good to find out that with "Simple CompizConfig" I can make that effect to show all windows when the mouse hits the top left corner =D

Comment: Good to know you found something good off all this... BTW: Wasn't "[Super]+W" doing the trick with the "show all windows"? Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In 11.04, the default is that if you drag a window to the top of the screen, then it is maximized. To the right or left edge, it is maximized horizontally, taking up half the width of the screen.

There is also keyboard shortcuts: ctrl+alt+1,3,9,7 places the window in the corresponding corner, taking up half the height and half the width of the screen. c-a+4,6 maximizes horizontally and uses half the width of the screen (like dragging it to the left or right) c-a+0 maximizes the window.

Lots of other awesomeness as well :)

Comment: Your answer doesnt state that it isnt available in 10.10.  You should note that they are discussing about 10.10, and not the glory that is 11.04

Comment: You're absolutely correct! Thanks for pointing that out. I'm still learning :)

Answer (score -1):

Gnome 3 comes with these features. Drag to the left or right and it fills that half of the screen, drag to the top and it maximizes, and drag a maximized window anywhere and it becomes normal size again. Unfortunately I can't seem to find a good link detailing this, but I'm using it right now.

Apparently GNOME 3 doesn't come with Ubuntu 11.04 by default, but there's a [GNOME 3 PPA](https://edge.launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) available according to [this GNOME blog post](http://blogs.gnome.org/rodrigo/2011/03/03/gnome3-on-ubuntu/).

GNOME 3's interface is a lot different than Windows though, so you may not like it. You can always remove it if you don't though.